# Add text to FAB in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button

How to add text to FAB ([Floating Action Button](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button)) bellow the icon as Google use in Maps?

I'm working with different languages versions, so I would like to put it there as a text, not as a vector only.

[image: Google Maps]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with [**`ExtendedFloatingActionButton`**](https://material.io/develop/android/components/extended-floating-action-button/).

> Extended floating action buttons are used for a special type of
>   promoted action. They are distinguished by an icon and a text floating
>   above the UI and have special motion behaviors related to morphing,
>   launching, and the transferring anchor point.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
          android:layout_width="56dp"
          android:layout_height="56dp"
          android:layout_margin="8dp"
          android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
          android:text="@string/go"
          android:textAllCaps="true"
          android:padding="8dp"
          app:iconPadding="-3dp"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_navigate"
          app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

[image: result FAB]

To use an **`ExtendedFloatingActionButton`** we need to import the google material components dependency as shown below

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it circular and keep both icon and text visible?

Comment: And why material:material:1.2.0-alpha03 is needed?

Comment: @Francis yes sir. Need this  components dependency

Comment: Of course I need material:material, but I thing no aplha is necessary. Is there used any feature from 1.2.0?